# c++ stl library what are these methods with underscores?

Tags: c++, stl, smart-pointers

I have some methods which are not referenced in any of the cpp references over the internet

For example in "memory"
Shared_ptr's have a method called "_Expired"

It returns a boolean if the ptr is expired or not

I thought that only weakptr's have this...

Comment: Where did you find these methods? They are probably some extensions.

Comment: I don't know. I am using visual studio 2013,  maybe it's that ?

Comment: Names staring with and underscore '_' are by convention reserved for internal use and implementation specific stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are internal functions that are part of the implementation. By having a name that starts with _ and an uppercase letter, they are defined as "implementation specific". Normal code should not use _ + uppercase names, so it's "safe" to for the implementation to use such names.

Note that there is nothing "meaningful" that you can get from these types of methods, member variables, etc, because it's part of the implementation, which will be different in a different system or using a different compiler, and even between different versions of the same STL implementation.

Exactly why a particular implementation is the way it is will be up to the designer of that implementation. Maybe they are sharing shared pointers implementation with weak pointer?

(The STL for g++ 4.6.3 doesn't have this particular construct!)

Answer (score 1):

There are many functions in STL methods/classes named starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (i.g. _Expired()). They are implemented mainly for internal use and are hidden to high level programmers.